# How to balance a video file's audio using FFmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have a video file with audio that is unbalanced - it's louder in one channel than the other.

Is it possible to fix this using FFmpeg?

Comment: Check out Audio filters: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Audio-Filters specifically dynaudnorm and loudnorm

Comment: @QuickPrototype Is normalisation definitely the way to go about this? I tried the Normalize filter in Audacity and it only seems to affect loudness, not channel balance, so I'm currently confused as to whether loudness normalisation with FFmpeg is the solution to this problem or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [stereotools](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#stereotools) filter.

Estimate and set the `balance_in` value. Try the various modes for `bmode_out`.